# Runtime difference reason for a LeetCode problem (Open the Lock)

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

LeetCod problem link:
https://leetcode.com/problems/open-the-lock/ (page [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZCq8.png))

Below is the code #1 doing a bfs from source and target:

```
from collections import deque

class Solution:
    def openLock(self, deadends: List[str], target: str) -> int:
        deadend = set(deadends)
        
        if target in deadend or '0000' in deadend:
            return -1
        
        if target == '0000':
            return 0
        
        def getNextCombi(combi: str) -> List[str]:
            res = []
            for i in range(4):
                nextCombi1 = combi[:i] + str((int(combi[i:i + 1]) + 1) % 10) + combi[i + 1:]
                nextCombi2 = combi[:i] + str((int(combi[i:i + 1]) - 1) % 10) + combi[i + 1:]
                if nextCombi1 not in deadend:
                    res.append(nextCombi1)
                if nextCombi2 not in deadend:
                    res.append(nextCombi2)
            return res
        
        sourceQueue = deque(['0000'])
        targetQueue = deque([target])
        
        sourceSeen = {'0000': 0}
        targetSeen = {target: 0}
        
        while len(sourceQueue) != 0 and len(targetQueue) != 0:
            sourceCombi = sourceQueue.popleft()
            targetCombi = targetQueue.popleft()
            
            for nextCombi in getNextCombi(sourceCombi):
                if nextCombi not in sourceSeen:
                    sourceSeen[nextCombi] = sourceSeen[sourceCombi] + 1
                    sourceQueue.append(nextCombi)
                    if nextCombi in targetSeen:
                        return sourceSeen[nextCombi] + targetSeen[nextCombi]
            
            for nextCombi in getNextCombi(targetCombi):
                if nextCombi not in targetSeen:
                    targetSeen[nextCombi] = targetSeen[targetCombi] + 1
                    targetQueue.append(nextCombi)
                    if nextCombi in sourceSeen:
                        return sourceSeen[nextCombi] + targetSeen[nextCombi]
        
        return -1
```

And Below is the code #2 doing a bfs from just source:

```
from collections import deque

class Solution:
    def openLock(self, deadends: List[str], target: str) -> int:
        deadend = set(deadends)
        
        if target in deadend or '0000' in deadend:
            return -1
        
        if target == '0000':
            return 0
        
        def getNextCombi(combi: str) -> List[str]:
            res = []
            for i in range(4):
                nextCombi1 = combi[:i] + str((int(combi[i:i + 1]) + 1) % 10) + combi[i + 1:]
                nextCombi2 = combi[:i] + str((int(combi[i:i + 1]) - 1) % 10) + combi[i + 1:]
                if nextCombi1 not in deadend:
                    res.append(nextCombi1)
                if nextCombi2 not in deadend:
                    res.append(nextCombi2)
            return res
        
        sourceQueue = deque(['0000'])
        
        sourceSeen = {'0000': 0}
        
        while len(sourceQueue) != 0:
            sourceCombi = sourceQueue.popleft()
            
            for nextCombi in getNextCombi(sourceCombi):
                if nextCombi not in sourceSeen:
                    sourceSeen[nextCombi] = sourceSeen[sourceCombi] + 1
                    sourceQueue.append(nextCombi)
                    if nextCombi == target:
                        return sourceSeen[nextCombi]
```

Code #1 gives around 120ms of speed on LeetCode,
and Code #2 gives around 640ms of speed on LeetCode.
I tried several times, so I believe there is a significant difference in the algorithm itself.

Why would #1 be much faster than #2?
I don't see the difference in terms of Time Complexity.
Is it just because the examples that are used in the LeetCode is more faster on #1?

My Analysis on both codes:
I think they have the same time complexity O(1) because in the worst case, it is going over all possibilities of the combination which is 4^9. I am not sure about my constant time-complexity, but I think I am right on that doing a bfs source -> target, and doing a bfs source -> meet <- target, is the same.

Comment: I suggest by first analyzing both algorithms for their time complexity. If you'd like help, take a first attempt and [edit] your question to describe your analysis.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: First of all, you need to focus on either running time (wall-clock or CPU time) **OR** algorithm complexity.  These are not the same thing.  Second, you need to analyze, profile, or otherwise understand your code to know what affects the metric you chose.  Finally, you need to share that with us and focus your question on the details you don't understand.  "Why is one faster than the other" is simply premature: it tries to transfer your analysis responsibilities to anyone who would respond to your post.

Comment: Im not sure why Im being judged on my question... it's just a simple question of why the runtime is different (either algorithmically or just because of how Leetcode is, etc.). I think that the time complexity in the worst case is just O(1) since it is O(4^10), and I wasn't sure about my analysis, so why not just ask like what I did?

Comment: @jginso7 In general if two algorithms are `O(1)` it doesn't mean they have same real running time, because any complexity `O(f(N))` actually means time `<= C * f(N)` where `C` is some constant fixed (and different) for each algorithm. For first of your algorithms constant `C` may be small, for second one large, hence very different running time. If you have some quite complex test in your mind that we can use please provide it, then we can measure time and number of Python instructions runned in both algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented C++ program to measure number of runned opcodes and lines in both of your algorithms. Why C++, not Python? Not because of C++ speed, but because only Python C API gives enough functionality to fine-grain your code-tracing function to set it to measure opcodes and lines.

Measurement results (output) of next C++ code are:

```
Traced 'algo1': time 3441700 nanoseconds, 1455 lines, 9304 opcodes,
    2365 avg ns/line, 369 avg ns/opcode.
Traced 'algo2': time 18011100 nanoseconds, 22678 lines, 155640 opcodes,
    794 avg ns/line, 115 avg ns/opcode.
```

Both algos were measured using next test input (taken from LeetCode example):

```
deadends = ['0201', '0101', '0102', '1212', '2002'], target = '0202'
```

So algo1 is much faster than algo2, algo1 executes only 9304 opcodes while algo2 executes 155640 opcode, i.e. 16 times more opcodes. What does it mean `opcode` - it is the smallest operation inside Python, same as instruction inside Assembler, but here opcode is instruction inside Python's virtual machine. Although some opcodes may take longer time than others still it is a good quantative measurement (number of opcodes).

It means even if both of your algorithms are `O(1)` still number of operations done in each algorithm is very different. Also remember that any complexity `O(f(N))` actually means that running time is `<= C * f(N)` where `C` is a fixed constant for each algorithm. E.g. your first algorithms may have `C = 1000` while your second algorithm may have `C = 9999`, both will have `O(1)` complexity but running time is `10x` different.

Also number of lines runned is very different. This number means how many lines have been passed in the code when executing algorithms. They are also good measurement of speed/time.

For simplicity you can also run just Python profiler (from standard library), using next lines of code:

```py
    import cProfile, profile
    with cProfile.Profile() as prof:
        Solution().openLock(deadends = ['0201', '0101', '0102', '1212', '2002'], 
            target = '0202')
    stats = pstats.Stats(prof).sort_stats('ncalls')
    stats.print_stats()
```

which gives for algo1:

```
         397 function calls in 0.003 seconds

   Ordered by: call count

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      161    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
      101    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'collections.deque' objects}
       22    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'popleft' of 'collections.deque' objects}
       22    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
       22    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
       21    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 C:\dev\tmp_code\main.py:17(getNextCombi)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.003    0.003 C:\dev\tmp_code\main.py:7(openLock)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 C:\bin\Python39\lib\typing.py:256(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 C:\bin\Python39\lib\cProfile.py:117(__exit__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

and for algo2:

```
         6261 function calls in 0.055 seconds

   Ordered by: call count

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     3093    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
      821    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'append' of 'collections.deque' objects}
      391    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
      390    0.021    0.000    0.040    0.000 C:\dev\tmp_code\main.py:17(getNextCombi)
      390    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'popleft' of 'collections.deque' objects}
      390    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        1    0.009    0.009    0.055    0.055 C:\dev\tmp_code\main.py:7(openLock)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 C:\bin\Python39\lib\typing.py:256(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 C:\bin\Python39\lib\cProfile.py:117(__exit__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

From both profiler's outputs above you can also see that algo2 does many more functions calls than algo1.

Next C++ code can be compiled using any compiler like MSVC/CLang/GCC on Windows/Linux/MacOS. In my case I compiled using CLang on Windows 10 64-bit. I used next command line to compile it `C:\bin\llvm\bin\clang++.exe -g -m64 -O3 -std=c++20 -Ic:/bin/python39/include main.cpp c:/bin/python39/libs/python39.lib`, here you have to provide correct path to your CLang and Python installations. If you want to install same CLang as I do then head to [LLVM releases](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-11.1.0) and download [LLVM-11.1.0-win64.exe](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-11.1.0/LLVM-11.1.0-win64.exe).

Here is C++ code itself:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow66912196#main.cpp)

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>

#include <Python.h>
struct _frame;

#define ASSERT(cond) { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error("Assertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "!"); }

class Tracer {
public:
    Tracer(std::string const & name)
        : name_(name) {
        PyEval_SetTrace(&Tracer::TraceFunc, nullptr);
        lines_cnt_ = 0;
        opcodes_cnt_ = 0;
        tb_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    ~Tracer() {
        auto te = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        PyEval_SetTrace(nullptr, nullptr);
        auto tp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(te - tb_).count();
        std::cout << "Traced '" << name_ << "': time " << tp << " nanoseconds, " << lines_cnt_ << " lines, " << opcodes_cnt_ << " opcodes, "
            << uint64_t(double(tp) / double(lines_cnt_)) << " avg ns/line, "            
            << uint64_t(double(tp) / double(opcodes_cnt_)) << " avg ns/opcode." << std::endl;
    }
    static int TraceFunc(PyObject * obj, _frame * frame, int what, PyObject * arg) {
        if (what == PyTrace_LINE)
            ++lines_cnt_;
        else if (what == PyTrace_OPCODE)
            ++opcodes_cnt_;
        return 0;
    }
private:
    static inline uint64_t opcodes_cnt_ = 0, lines_cnt_ = 0;
    std::string name_;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tb_;
};

void Measure() {
    {
        ASSERT(PyRun_SimpleString(R"(
from collections import deque
from typing import List
import inspect
        )") == 0);
    }
    {
        Tracer tracer("algo1");
        ASSERT(PyRun_SimpleString(R"(
try:
    from collections import deque
    from typing import List
    import inspect

    class Solution:
        def openLock(self, deadends: List[str], target: str) -> int:
            inspect.currentframe().f_trace_opcodes = True
            deadend = set(deadends)
            
            if target in deadend or '0000' in deadend:
                return -1
            
            if target == '0000':
                return 0
            
            def getNextCombi(combi: str) -> List[str]:
                inspect.currentframe().f_trace_opcodes = True
                res = []
                for i in range(4):
                    nextCombi1 = combi[:i] + str((int(combi[i:i + 1]) + 1) % 10) + combi[i + 1:]
                    nextCombi2 = combi[:i] + str((int(combi[i:i + 1]) - 1) % 10) + combi[i + 1:]
                    if nextCombi1 not in deadend:
                        res.append(nextCombi1)
                    if nextCombi2 not in deadend:
                        res.append(nextCombi2)
                return res
            
            sourceQueue = deque(['0000'])
            targetQueue = deque([target])
            
            sourceSeen = {'0000': 0}
            targetSeen = {target: 0}
            
            while len(sourceQueue) != 0 and len(targetQueue) != 0:
                sourceCombi = sourceQueue.popleft()
                targetCombi = targetQueue.popleft()
                
                for nextCombi in getNextCombi(sourceCombi):
                    if nextCombi not in sourceSeen:
                        sourceSeen[nextCombi] = sourceSeen[sourceCombi] + 1
                        sourceQueue.append(nextCombi)
                        if nextCombi in targetSeen:
                            return sourceSeen[nextCombi] + targetSeen[nextCombi]
                
                for nextCombi in getNextCombi(targetCombi):
                    if nextCombi not in targetSeen:
                        targetSeen[nextCombi] = targetSeen[targetCombi] + 1
                        targetQueue.append(nextCombi)
                        if nextCombi in sourceSeen:
                            return sourceSeen[nextCombi] + targetSeen[nextCombi]
            
            return -1

    Solution().openLock(deadends = ['0201', '0101', '0102', '1212', '2002'], target = '0202')
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    print(flush = True)
        )") == 0);
    }
    {
        Tracer tracer("algo2");
        ASSERT(PyRun_SimpleString(R"(
try:
    from collections import deque
    from typing import List
    import inspect

    class Solution:
        def openLock(self, deadends: List[str], target: str) -> int:
            inspect.currentframe().f_trace_opcodes = True
            deadend = set(deadends)
            
            if target in deadend or '0000' in deadend:
                return -1
            
            if target == '0000':
                return 0
            
            def getNextCombi(combi: str) -> List[str]:
                inspect.currentframe().f_trace_opcodes = True
                res = []
                for i in range(4):
                    nextCombi1 = combi[:i] + str((int(combi[i:i + 1]) + 1) % 10) + combi[i + 1:]
                    nextCombi2 = combi[:i] + str((int(combi[i:i + 1]) - 1) % 10) + combi[i + 1:]
                    if nextCombi1 not in deadend:
                        res.append(nextCombi1)
                    if nextCombi2 not in deadend:
                        res.append(nextCombi2)
                return res
            
            sourceQueue = deque(['0000'])
            
            sourceSeen = {'0000': 0}
            
            while len(sourceQueue) != 0:
                sourceCombi = sourceQueue.popleft()
                
                for nextCombi in getNextCombi(sourceCombi):
                    if nextCombi not in sourceSeen:
                        sourceSeen[nextCombi] = sourceSeen[sourceCombi] + 1
                        sourceQueue.append(nextCombi)
                        if nextCombi == target:
                            return sourceSeen[nextCombi]

    Solution().openLock(deadends = ['0201', '0101', '0102', '1212', '2002'], target = '0202')
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    print(flush = True)
        )") == 0);
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        Py_SetProgramName(L"main.py");
        Py_Initialize();
        Measure();
        Py_FinalizeEx();
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```